# Check for missing field or null value in mongoDB atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I am using mongodb atlas for full text search.
My sample collection looks like this :

```
{
  "_id": "62fdfd7518da050007f035c5",
  "expiryDate": "2022-08-18T23:59:59+05:30",
  "arrayField" : ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
},
{
  "_id": "62fdfd7518da050007f035c6",
  "expiryDate": null,
  "arrayField" : ['abc','jkl']
},
{
  "_id": "62fdfd7518da050007f035c7",
  "arrayField" : []
},
{
  "_id": "62fdfd7518da050007f035c8",
  "expiryDate": null
}
```

`expiryDate` is a `Date` type field and `arrayField` is an `Array` type field.

My goal is to get all documents where either :

1. `expiryDate` doesn't exists OR
2. If `expiryDate` does exists, then it must be null OR
3. If `expiryDate` does exists, then it must greater than current time.

My current atlas aggregation looks like :

```
{
    'compound' : {
        'should' : [
            {
                'compound' : {
                    'mustNot' : [{
                        "exists": {
                            "path": "expiryDate",
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            {
                "range": {
                    "path": "expiryDate",
                    'gte': new Date()
                }
            }
        ],
        'minimumShouldMatch' : 1
    }
}
```

This is not returning all documents where the `expiryDate` field have `null` value and it is only matching one clause of should where `expiryDate` is greater than or equal to current time. I want it to return all those documents too where the `expiryDate` is `null`.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried with multiple clauses and approaches and found that there are two solutions to this problem :

1. Use combination of $must, $should and $mustNot :

```
{
    'compound' : {
        'should' : [
            {
                'compound' : {
                    'mustNot' : [{
                        "exists": {
                            "path": "expiryDate",
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            {
              "compound": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "path": "expiryDate"
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "mustNot": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "path": "expiryDate",
                      "lt": new Date()
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
            {
                "range": {
                    "path": "expiryDate",
                    'gte': new Date()
                }
            }
        ],
        'minimumShouldMatch' : 1
    }
}
```

And the second one is rather not optimized but works. Since at the end it's and aggregation; We can use `$match` operator just outside the `$search` pipeline like so :

```
db.exampleCollection.aggregate([
  {
    "$search": {
      "index": "default",
      "compound": {
        "must": [
          ...some conditions
        ],
        "filter": [
          ...some clauses
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": [...some other conditions]
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      ...some fields
    }
  },
  {
    "$skip": 0
  },
  {
    "$limit": 10
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "score": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$exists` operator ([docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/exists/)) to check if an element exists, and if it does, run a check on its value.

Comment: Thanks but the docs you shared are for mongo and not for mongo atlas. They are different. If possible can you please put the updated query, that would definitely help me .

Comment: @PawanSaxena I just updated the link, sorry but I misread and thought you were working with mongo. It looks like MA has the exists operator, but it works a little differently. I'm not sure if it lets you run the check I mentioned, like checking if a value is greater than another value.

Comment: the exists check in atlas explicitly checks if a field exists or not. I wanted to have this check along with check that if it does exists then how can i combine that with null value?

Answer (score 0):

@PawanSaxena I'm trying to do something similar, i.e., finding documents whose date field exists (and) with null value. Did you test out just the 2nd goal in your original post.  Somehow it didn't work for me. Here is my testing code:

```
{
  "compound": {
    "must": [
      {
        "exists": {
          "path": "expiryDate"
        }
      }
    ],
    "mustNot": [   /// should it be "must"?
      {
        "range": {
          "path": "expiryDate",
          "lt": new Date()  /// see below _MONGOSH, new Date() will output current date 
          // "lt": 1   /// this doesn't work, either
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @larry the best way is to use $match and use the stored source option, it works and doesn't give performance issues.